# Missing template pages/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>["text/*"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every once in a while my app would throw the following error:

```
Missing template pages/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>["text/*"]
```

The weird thing is that pages/index is pretty much a static page with no logic.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pagetitle = "Homepage"
  end
end
```

Does anybody know which browsers request the text/* format and how to replicate and/or fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in your controller, if it helps:

```
before_filter :force_request_format_to_html

private

def force_request_format_to_html
  request.format = :html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mime::Type for this case in config/initializers/mime_types.rb.

`Mime::Type.register "text/html", :html, %w( application/xhtml+xml text/* ), %w( xhtml )`